# Guard rspec doesn't run specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard, spring-gem

When spec or model changed, guard with options `spring rspec` shows next output:

```
04:54:44 - INFO - Running: spec/models/identity_spec.rb
Version: 1.1.2

Usage: spring COMMAND [ARGS]

Commands for spring itself:

  binstub         Generate spring based binstubs. Use --all to generate a binstub for all known commands.
  help            Print available commands.
  status          Show current status.
  stop            Stop all spring processes for this project.

Commands for your application:

  rails           Run a rails command. The following sub commands will use spring: console, runner, generate, destroy.
  rake            Runs the rake command


Frame number: 0/0
```

I'm using `ruby '2.1.0'` and `'rails', '4.1.0.rc1'` with spring. So, it looks like it doesn't run anything. I tried different cmd options.

```
guard :rspec do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

  # Rails example
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }
end
```

This throws en error:

```
05:04:08 - INFO - Running: spec/models/identity_spec.rb
05:04:08 - ERROR - Guard::RSpec failed to achieve its <run_on_modifications>, exception was:
> [#] NoMethodError: undefined method `parse_options' for #<RSpec::Core::ConfigurationOptions:0x007fad670937a8 @args=[]>
> [#] /Users/alder/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/guard-rspec-4.2.2/lib/guard/rspec/command.rb:33:in `_rspec_formatters'
> [#] /Users/alder/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/guard-rspec-4.2.2/lib/guard/rspec/command.rb:29:in `_visual_formatter'
> [#] /Users/alder/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/guard-rspec-4.2.2/lib/guard/rspec/command.rb:21:in `_parts'
> [#] /Users/alder/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/guard-rspec-4.2.2/lib/guard/rspec/command.rb:14:in `initialize'
```

Full content [there](https://gist.github.com/zishe/9677571) with spec helper

I've tried all different variations of options `rspec`, `spring rspec spec` and other possible including without any, but had the same result.

`rspec spec` without guard works fine.

I found [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22327463/guard-rspec-and-spring-command-cmd-spring-rspec-doesnt-run-the-specs-within), but it works without spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. In `guard-rspec/guard-rspec.gemspec` from 4.2.2 version, line:

```
   s.add_dependency 'rspec', '>= 2.14', '< 4.0'
```

Conflicted with beta version i guess. So i changed it on next:

```
   s.add_dependency 'rspec', '>= 2.14', '~> 3.0.0.beta2', '< 4.0'
```

And it works!

And by the way, option `spring` in `cmd` caused test to do nothing. So, works this:

```
   guard :rspec, cmd: 'rspec -f doc --color --require spec_helper ' do
```

And just `guard :rspec do`, and it consider options from `.rspec` file, in which i wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
guard 'rspec', :cli => '--drb' do
  #your code
end
```

once I wrote this [quick guild](https://gist.github.com/sameera207/4304166) for my reference, see if that works for you

HIH

Comment: `--drb` is a Spork option, which i haven't. So, same error.

Comment: `cli` also didn't help.